# Is there a way to set the priority of the background thread used by a SwingWorker?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, thread-priority

In Java is there a way to set the priority for the thread that will be calling the `doInBackground()` method of a `SwingWorker` object?

In the Thread API there is a `setPriority()` method. The `SwingWorker.execute()` method schedules the swingworker for execution on a worker thread. I would like to have access to that worker thread to set it's priority.

From my understanding this worker thread comes from a default worker thread pool. Would the only way to handle this is to use my own executor?

Comment: Unless you are using close to 100% of all your CPUs, setting the priority might not make any difference. If you are using all your CPU, the priority is just a hint which the JVM or OS is free to ignore. IMHO Its not going to solve your problem.

Comment: The application is specifically targeting Windows and the JVM is the standard Oracle JVM. From this other stack overflow question it does make some difference in this scenario:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297804/thread-api-priority-translation-to-os-thread-priority

Comment: It makes a difference to the hint given to the OS. Whether it makes any difference at all when you are not using all the cpu, is the question I have.  AFAIK, if you have spare cpu every thread which can run will run regardless of priority. It only matters when the OS has to make a choice that priority matters.

Comment: @Peter, Windows uses the process base prir and the thread prir to factor some overall prir. On a side note: increasing prir can make a thread interfere w/ the GC threads and you always want GC threads to run 1st.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JDK7 [SwingWorker javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) hints that the designers did not intend for users to directly interact with or alter the background threads:

`... the exact strategy of choosing a thread for any particular SwingWorker is unspecified and should not be relied on.`

The implementation of SwingWorker.getWorkersExecutorService() seems to reinforce this idea as they've implemented it in a way that is not easily changed.

SwingWorker is a boilerplate solution to the typical case and you don't have a typical case.  I'd suggest you write the code to handle running the background tasks instead of trying to hack SwingWorker to do what you want. That way whoever gets to maintain your code in the future (perhaps even yourself!) won't be left wondering why SwingWorker isn't behaving as expected.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I can think to do this is to have the execute method grab the current thread using `Thread.currentThread()`. You can then set the priority of this thread (provided the caller is allowed to).

Comment: I think this method could work. `Thread.currentThread()` should be executed in "doInBackground()" method (worker thread).

Comment: This seemed to work. I think I might need to switch it back to it's default priority at the end of the method since the thread will be returned to a pool and will be used for something else. Like Jason Braucht said this might be a bad design.

Answer (score 2):

As the SwingWorker is a `Runnable`, you can submit it to any `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`